# Auto reload of HTML table just makes it disappear

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, which generates a HTML table from a Google Spreadsheet. I am attempting to make *just the table* auto refresh every 5 seconds, while the spreadsheet loads. However, when using the following code, it just makes the table disappear after 5 seconds. Does anyone see what is wrong or have a better solution?

```
<div class="sheetstotables"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableId = "AB12C"
var x = document.createElement("script"); x.type = "text/javascript"; x.async = true;
x.src = "http://www.sheetstotables.com/get_table.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(x, s);
</script>


   <script>
 function autoRefresh_div()
 {
      $(".sheetstotables").load("load.html");// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
  }

  setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 5000); // refresh div after 5 secs
            </script>
```

Comment: Use the "network" tab in F12, see what data is returned.

Comment: What is F12? You mean on the keyboard... I am using a mac, where F12 is just the eject key.

Comment: Whichever browser you are using, there will be one option called as **Developer tools**, Just check whether you are getting any errors or what data is being receive over **http response**

Comment: I am getting a few errors: 1) Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.           2) Cannot read property 'responseText' of null  3) net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Are you running this locally?

Answer (score 0):

You may not run this locally ( You must run this in a server ). Try to put this on [github.io](https://pages.github.com/) by creating a repo. named *yourgithubname*.github.io or put it on your own server and run it again.

---

You can only use `load` if you URL start with any of the following:

`http://`, `data:`, `chrome://`, `chrome-extension://`, `https://` or `chrome-extension-resource`.

If you URL is like `file:///`, then you couldn't do this.